# How to include extra fragments onto a ViewPager, in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am currently using a `ViewPager` with a `TabLayout`, the `ViewPager` as of now consists of three separate fragments.

I would like to be able to switch to a fourth fragment using a button on one of the already present fragments.

However, I do not want the fourth fragment to be accessible through the usual ways (aka scrolling) without using the button to reach the fourth fragment. Similarly, I would like scrolling to be disabled when I am currently displaying my fourth fragment.

What would be the best way to do so?

The current hack that I can think of would be to create a hidden fragment within my main layout. I can then display it when the button is pressed while hiding the `ViewPager` at the same time.

Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Include your ViewPager in fragment and onClick make replace for the next fragment, and you can return to ViewPager`s fragment onBackPress.